# Is there a macro for adding nonatomic to all @property declarations?

Tags: objective-c, clang

`NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` & `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` provide nice wrappers for the clang pragma:

`#pragma clang assume_nonnull begin` & `#pragma clang assume_nonnull end`

Is there an equivalent macro which allows me to skip the `nonatomic` in `@property` declarations which don't already include it?

Comment: A simple macro which works as long as you don't have any atomic properties is: `#define property(...) property(nonatomic,__VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: #define PROPERTY(...) @property(nonatomic,__VA_ARGS__) will work, but would recommend to make your MACRO in all caps, to distinguish that you are using a macro. This is just good coding style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe their is a pragma for the nonatomic in the Objective-C property declarations. Here is a list of all the Clang attributes and documentation in  [Clang 3.9 Documentation - Attributes](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html). You can find out everything else about clang by reading the entire [Clang 3.9 Documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links, I changed the question to 'what's the macro definition' since no pragma exists.